# Remove &nbsp; instances from string

Tags: php, string, int

How can I remove instances of `&nbsp;` from a string?

For example, `$var = "10&nbsp;999&nbsp;999";` would change to `$var = 10999999;`

(I have tried using `preg_replace()` to no avail.)

Comment: Show us the code that you tried, you might have been almost there.

Comment: Instead of just stating that something didn't work, show the specific code which didn't. [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) would be simpler, btw.

Comment: `$var = preg_replace('/&nbsp;/', '', $var);`

Comment: *"I've tried to use `preg_replace()` but it didn't work."* - Always show what you've tried. That way, we can show you where you may have done wrong; in turn, you learn ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) will work, your regex needs to be something like this:

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

first string replace the non breaking spaces since its a string, then use (int) to convert the output to an integer:

```
$var = "10&nbsp;999&nbsp;999";
$intvar = (int)str_replace('&nbsp;','',$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, this will also force cast of var to an integer

```
$var = "10&nbsp;999&nbsp;999";
$var = (int)preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/', '', $var);
```

& Running a test:

```
$var = "10&nbsp;999&nbsp;999";
$var = (int)preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/', '', $var);

echo gettype($var);
```

yields: *integer*